# Remove upload button and filename during image upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-uploading

Using the given form, I first click on "Choose File", open the file,its name comes next to it 
and then I click on "Upload" button" to upload the image.What I want to do is click on "Choose File", open the file but the name should not appear next to it and the image should get uploaded without clicking the "Upload button" after this.How can this be achieved?

```
   <div id="image_container" name="image_container">
        <img src="../image/ab.jpg"  alt="Cover" width="900px" height="500px">
        <div class="btn-group" id="cov" name="cov" >
           <button  class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="mybtn" onclick="dropdown()">Action</button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" style="display:none">
<!-- dropdown menu links -->
            <li><form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadForm">  
                <input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file" />
                <label id="fileup" for="imageInput">Upload File</label>
                <input type="submit"  id="submit-btn" value="Upload" />
                <img src="img/loader.gif" id="loading-img" style="display:none;" alt="Please Wait"/>
                </form>
                <div id="output"></div>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target: '#output', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit, // pre-submit callback 
        success: afterSuccess, // post-submit callback 
        resetForm: true // reset the form after successful submit 
    }; 

    $('#MyUploadForm').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);            
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruwuv/1/)**.

If you are using jQuery,

```
$('#imageInput').change(function(){
    $("#submit-btn").click();          //$('#MyUploadForm').submit();
});
```

Or Just,

```
<input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file" onChange="this.submit();" />
```

To hide the filename, you have to manipulate the css, or hide the whole button and place another button in it.

Comment: It works but can you tell how can I have a normal text like "Upload image" on clicking which we get to upload the image instead of clicking "Choose File" in the form?

Comment: I have edited my html.If I use label as per your suggestions then "Upload File" appears differently from the other members of the list and even the cursor does not change its shape

Comment: You need to change its position using css.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("imageInput").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("MyUploadForm").submit();
};
```

Comment: You can add it before declaring the options variable. Before this: `var options = {`

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
<input name="ImageFile" id="imageInput" type="file"
onChange="this.submit();this.visibility='hidden';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `label` to create your own upload button and just hide the `input` itself.

HTML

```
<form action="#">
  <label for="upload">Pretend Button</lable>
  <input type="file" id="upload" name="image">
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#upload').on('change', function () {
  $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
});
```

CSS

```
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9999px;;
}
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/rirupeco/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a lil user experience trick and also inspiration for your request:

When files selected and clicking OK in file-selection-window, it should upload right after. No extra click on Submit, by this:

```
var flag_fileSelection = false;

$("#element").click(function(){
    flag_fileSelection = true;
})

$(window).focus(function(){
    if (flag_fileSelection) {
        flag_fileSelection = false;

        // user is done choosing files
        $("#form").submit();

    }   
})
```